# How to find style text that was previosly set on a feature - OL3

Tags: openlayers-3

Using OL3, I set the text on a style dynamically:

```
var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: mySource,
            style: function (feature, resolution) {
                var style = new ol.style.Style({
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        text: setText(feature)
                    })
                });

                return [style];
            }
        });
```

I am trying to later read what is stored in text:

```
text: setText(feature)
```

I am trying to retrieve the text on a click event but not sure how to access that property under the feature style (feature is the variable from the event containing the clicked feature):

```
// Get current display text
var currentFeatureStyle = feature.getStyle();
```

But when I do that, I get a null currentFeatureStyle.

Also tried looping through the feature:

```
for (var fid in feature)
{
//what to look for to extract the feature text?
```

But not sure what to look for to extract the feature text.  Any help getting back the feature text from a feature would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone can come up with a more correct answer please by all means post below.  I have created a "workaround" since I could not retrieve the text from the feature.  The workaround involves the following:

1. Inside the method the text is originally set, add the following:

   ```
   function setText(feature)
   {

       // First do your normal stuff (set the text of the feature)
       var output = "myFeatureText";

       // Here is the workaround step 1:
       // Create a property and set it to the text
       feature.displayText = output;

       // Return back value for the setting of the style text
       return output;
   }
   ```

Now the text is also saved in a property called displayText.  Note: displayText is a made up property, it does not exist in openlayers.

2. Step 2 is to retrieve the property you created in step 1 to get the display text.  In this example we are retrieving the feature from singleclick but it can be from anywhere else you are using the feature:

   ```
   map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {

   var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
                   function (feature, layer) {
                       return feature;
                   });

   // Here is the workaround step 2:

   // Get "display text" custom field for this feature

   var displayText = feature.displayText;
   ```

   .

And thats all there is to it.  There must be a "correct" way to retrieve the text from the style of the feature but I am not aware of it.  If someone know how to by all means post your answer.